# Testing Azure dead letter service bus queues

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azureservicebus

We have a service which listens to a Azure service bus queue.  We have another service which listens to the dead letter queue of this queue.  We also have a series of tests which run against our Azure application when it has have been deployed.

We would like to extend our automated tests so that the parts that deal with the dead letters are also tested, but are not sure how we can write tests which will ensure that messages get to the dead letter queue, as under normal circumstances messages will not dead letter.

currently we are testing this manually, but I feel like this is not a long term option.

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Service Bus API, Microsoft doesn't provide ability to send message to dead letter queue straight away without putting message to the main queue. If you try to create [MessageSender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesender.aspx) using path to dead letter queue, it will fail with exception.

You need to mock out your main queue receiver with fake implementation that invokes [BrokeredMessage.DeadLetter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter.aspx) method that transfers message to dead letter queue.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Service Bus [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration.aspx), if you set `EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration` to true, if a message expires it goes to the dead letter queue. So, you can do:

```
var desc = new QueueDescription(QueueName);
desc.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;
desc.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // one second is the min value
```

You can test by just waiting > 1 second to ensure that the message goes to the dead letter queue.

**Edit**: You can also dead letter a received message by doing `receivedMessage.DeadLetter()`. This will automatically place it in the dead letter queue.

Comment: Thanks @TheDude but the queue is already created as part of deployment of the system and has its timings set up for what we need. And what if the service processing the messages picks it up before it expires, ie before the 1 second has expired?  this approach might have some value, but seems fraught with timing problem possibilities.

Comment: @SamHolder I included another approach in my answer.